# x86 asm instruction set: Any _searchable_ offline reference?

Tags: assembly, x86, manual, instruction-set

I'm somewhat new to assembly and have to look up the x86 instructions every now and then. Searching the web for every other opcode gets annoying after a while. Then there are the Intel Reference Manuals, but the contents page doesn't have direct links to the various sections in the pdf file, and doesn't list the 'true' page name but instead numbers things by [chapter]-[relative page number], <strike>and I have to use that to guess the page number of the opcode</strike>.

So the question is, is there any efficiently searchable offline reference for x86 instructions?

I vaguely remember that the CheatEngine disassembler provided some info for each opcode you clicked on in the disassembly. However it's Windows-only, and these days I use Linux most of the time. But something like that would be nice.

**Edit:** Well, I realize I can search for that chapter-pagenum string in the pdf, which is probably unique. But I'd still prefer a something I can type an opcode into and get the info straight back out.

Comment: Foxit Reader can handle 'true' page numbers, I believe.

Comment: Hmm, haven't tried that reader. But the manuals don't provide 'true' page numbers in the contents.

Comment: If you have Intel's instruction set reference in PDF, just look up the instruction in the index.

Comment: After your edit, I understand less and less why you don't just search the opcode name in the PDF body. It's as unique as the chapter-pagenum string, and there is one less indirection.

Comment: .. actually, I wanted to delete the question, but it was too late. incidentally, searching 'ror' will turn up 'error'.. but yeah, most opcodes shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that the Intel ref manuals come with a useful built-in indexing mechanism. Surprisingly enough, it is called the index.

Answer (score 7):

Parts 2a and 2b of the Intel manuals (free download):

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

EDIT; If you're using OS X, then there is a Service (app) available which does exactly that. IIRC, installs with the CHUD tool set. (Originally omitted because it was not assumed that OS X was the platform, but still noteworthy).

Comment: Yeah, sounds like what I would want.. but I don't use OS X. (Would remove downvote if you edited your post; right now the vote is too old to remove without an edit.)

Answer (score 3):

[Opcode Reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/)
I find this one somewhat overkill, but maybe it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: never mind, answering another question I realized that this manual used `gas` (also called AT&T) syntax, this is not what you want if you want an equivalent of the Intel reference manuals. I had not paid attention because I use `gas` myself.

---

What about [this one](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/817-5477/817-5477.pdf), courtesy of Sun? I've used it. Also I am not sure I understand what your problem is, but maybe that's because my pdf reader can search keywords directly in the PDF. You would solve this problem and more if you found one for Linux with a similar feature.